Cannot navigate on page load in react.js
I am trying to access a route which should redirect the user back to homepage when postOperations isn't set in the localStorage.
Here's the code, just check the useEffect and first component inside return() to save your time.
import AppBarComp from "./AppBarComp";
import { Container, Box, Typography, TextField, Button } from '@mui/material'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Context } from './Context'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import  { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { toast } from 'sonner';
import { PostOperationsContextFunction } from "./Context";



export default function AddPost() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { localStorageOperation } = PostOperationsContextFunction();
    const [postTitle, setPostTitle] = useState('');
    const [postContent, setPostContent] = useState('');
    const theme = useContext(Context);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorageOperation === 'null') {
            navigate('/homepage');
        }
    }, [localStorageOperation, navigate]);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Post Title: " + postTitle + "\n" + "Post Context: " + postContent);
        try {
            const data = await pushBlogPostFunction();
            console.log(data);
            toast.info("Successfully posted the blog", {
                duration: 1000,
                position: 'bottom-center',
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                navigate('/homepage')
            }, 1500)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    const pushBlogPostFunction = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/", { postTitle: postTitle, postContent: postContent }, { withCredentials: true })
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        {(localStorageOperation == 'null') && <Navigate to="/homepage" />}
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <AppBarComp />
                <Container maxWidth="xl" element="main" sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
                    {localStorageOperation == 'addPost' ? 
                        < Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} element="div"
                    sx={{
                        width: "90%",
                        maxWidth: "600px",
                        textAlign: "center", boxShadow: "2px 2px 10px 5px hsl(179, 100%, 0%, 0.2)",
                        borderRadius: "10px", padding: "30px 40px"
                    }}>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5" textAlign={"left"} sx={{ fontWeight: "bolder", fontSize: "1.8em" }}>
                        Compose your post
                    </Typography>
                    { }
                    <TextField required inputProps={{ minLength: 10 }} onChange={(event) => setPostTitle(event.target.value)} id="standard-basic" label="Title" variant="outlined" margin="normal" fullWidth />
                    <TextField required inputProps={{ minLength: 10 }} onChange={(event) => setPostContent(event.target.value)} id="standard-basic" label="Content" variant="outlined" multiline rows={4} margin="normal" fullWidth />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }} >
                        Post
                    </Button>
                </Box>
: ""
}
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider >
        </>
    )
}

I am using navigate both programmatically and as a component just to show you guys both don't work for me.
I tried to redirect back to the homepage and I was expecting navigate to work

What does PostOperationsContextFunction() return? Just null or string 'null'?

What is the body of localStorageOperation? I assume you have compared the wrong variable types: null is not equal to 'null'

OMG, You guys are right! I was null type but i was comparing it with the string. Thank you all!!

It was just a wrong comparison. I had to compare 'null' as a type instead of string.
